# Program for register work time / task

Tags: software-recommendation, time, project-management

I'm looking for a program in which I and my small team can register the number of hours it takes to do a certain task. This would be registered daily and if possible would also be free or close to it.

Thanks
Vasco

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7273/how-to-stay-productive-what-time-management-software-is-available

Answer (score 2):

A couple of choices here between web-based or desktop

Web based type you have [TRAC](http://trac.edgewall.org/) or [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/)

Desktop type [GanttProject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/) or [Hamster](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/08/08/hamster-time-tracking-for-gnome/)

#### Hamster is by far the simplest and available in the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Another web based option is [Anuko Time Tracker](http://www.anuko.com/content/time_tracker/index.htm)